# How can I access window.orientation of parent window from inside a cross-domain iframe?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, mobile

I have tried various ways of accessing a parent window's orientation variable, but it always seems to be either "undefined" or "null".

Here are the different ways I've tried accessing the parent window's orientation:

```
parent.window.orientation
window.parent.orientation
window.opener.orientation
parent.document.orientation (shouldn't work, but I tried anyway)
parent.orientation
```

I've also tried listening for the "orientationChanged" event:

```
parent.document.addEventListener('orientationChanged',function() {
    alert('orientation changed');
    });
```

None of the above methods are able to detect the orientation of an iframe parent.

Unfortunately, I am required to use iframes.  I am designing a mobile page that will be placed into a cross-domain iframe.  Preferably, I want to be able to detect an orientation change from within the iframe instead of having the client put extra javascript on their page.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

Comment: I know that postMessage() is an option, but I was wondering if there was a way to get the parent orientation without having to add any extra Javascript to the parent page.